# Qt QGraphicsView OpenGL viewport issue

Tags: qt, opengl, qgraphicsview

I subclassed QGraphicsView (to extend functionality) and put it to my gui using QtDesigner with promoting it to necessary class.

To accelerate graphics rendering i desided to set vieport of my graphics view to QGLWidget (but left all scene items be rendered by QPainter). Doing it like was suggested by Qt doc and other people:
`ui->graphicsView->setViewport(new QGLWidget(QGLFormat(QGL::SampleBuffers)));`

Unfortunatly because of gui style main widget, which is used as container to put all other widgets in layouts, has attribute `setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);`. It was made for drop shadow effect in minimized program state.

The problem is that such combination of code makes hole in displayed gui (take a look at screenshot below).

[image: problem]

Removing that flag gives necessary graphics rendering acceleration but all stylesheets of main window are cease to work (eg. buttons do not react on hover event).

Add:

Here is code totally reproducing the problem:

```
`#include <QtOpenGL/QGL>

main_form::main_form(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    setWindowFlag(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
    resize(400, 300);

    effect = new QGraphicsDropShadowEffect;
    effect->setBlurRadius(25);
    effect->setOffset(0);
    setGraphicsEffect(effect);

    QHBoxLayout *main_lay = new QHBoxLayout;
    setLayout(main_lay);

    QWidget *handler = new QWidget(this);
    handler->setStyleSheet(QString("background-color: white;"));
    QTreeWidget *tree = new QTreeWidget(this);
    QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView(this);

    main_lay->addWidget(handler);
    QHBoxLayout *handle_lay = new QHBoxLayout;
    handler->setLayout(handle_lay);
    handle_lay->addWidget(tree);
    handle_lay->addWidget(view);

    view->setViewport(new QGLWidget(QGLFormat(QGL::SampleBuffers)));
}

main_form::~main_form()
{
    delete effect;
}`
```

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that exhibits the problem? There's not enough to go on from the description.

Comment: I add code in main part.

Comment: Still looking for help.

Comment: By adding the translucent flag to your window, you're asking the GUI not to paint anything behind it. Since you're presumably not drawing anything on top of it, you're seeing through to whatever is underneath. In this case, the background. So you created the hole. I don't think this flag is what you need.

Comment: Ok. Will try to find another way how to solve this problem.